# Android program in Eclipse if statement not working

Tags: android, android-intent, if-statement

I wrote the following code in a part of Android program, but it is not working as expected, instead it is just printing contents in variable message_2. Following is my code

```
public void sendCall(View view){
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, DisplayCallActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);

    String message_2 = editText.getText().toString();
    String message = "Mahesh";
    //String message_1 = "Kumar";

    if (message_2 == "M")
    {
        intent1.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
    else
    {
        intent1.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Unknown");
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
```

Any help on this would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your condition like this `if(message_2.equals("M"))`

Answer (score 3):

With java you cannot compare strings with a `==`.  You must use the following:

```
message_2.equals("M")
```

Comment: Damn, have been using Perl for too long now!!!